# Sklearn iterative Impture creating more nans

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset of size `(1250,13)`. With unfortunalty quite a lot of NaNs, but there should be quite a lot of correlation between columns.

I tried using the `sklearn.impute` `IterativeImputer` which resulted in the following.
Also I am aware that it is still in the experimental stage.

```py
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
print(df.isna().sum())

imp_mean = IterativeImputer(random_state=42, max_iter = 100)
float_columns = df[relevant_cols].to_numpy()
imp_mean.fit(float_columns)
float_columns = imp_mean.transform(float_columns)
df[relevant_cols] = pd.DataFrame(float_columns, columns = relevant_cols)
print("after imputation:")
print(df.isna().sum())
```

Which results in the output:

```
ID                                  0
col a                               7
col b                              10
col c                              26
col d                              27
col e                              25
col f                             181
col g                             189
col h                             291
col i                             454
col j                             294
col k                             267
dtype: int64
after imputation:
ID                                  0
col a                             248
col b                             248
col c                             248
col d                             248
col e                             248
col f                             248
col g                             248
col h                             248
col i                             248
col j                             248
col k                             248
dtype: int64
```

As you can probabily tell, the ID column does not get used for the imputation.
I look at the sourcecode of the module but could not find a reason for this behavior.
Is the count of NaN too big?

I am gratefull for any help.

Edit:
With the kind help of seralouk I did some digging. Turns out if change the transform column to:

```
imputed_data = pd.DataFrame(float_columns, columns = relevant_cols)
print(imputed_data.isna().sum())
```

there are not any NaN values.
Only when I copy them back to the original df there are 248 each again.

Comment: can you post some data?

Comment: Unfortinatly not, but if it helps you help me, I might spend some time and try to recreate this issue with generated data.

Comment: see my answer. something is wrong

Comment: ok, looks like  the problem lies in not creating a new dataframe, but copying straight to the old one. Its still something I can't recreate in your very helpfull example. But its something.  If I create a new dataframe there are no NaNs. Once if copy their values into the old dataframe everything is back to 248 NaNs

Comment: So it looks like I have a Pandas problem and not a imputing problem

Comment: I just said that some seconds ago below my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is unexpected behavior. Can you post some data? What is your `sklearn` version ? Type `import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)`.

Also, can you try to store pd.DataFrame(float_columns, columns = relevant_cols) in a new dataframe and not use df[relevant_cols] = pd.DataFrame(float_columns, columns = relevant_cols).

Here is a toy example using 0.23.2 version of `sklearn`:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

np.random.seed(0)

x = np.random.rand(10,5)
x[np.random.randint(0,2,size=x.shape).astype(np.bool)] = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
print(df.isna().sum())


imp_mean = IterativeImputer(random_state=42, max_iter = 100)
float_columns = df.to_numpy()
imp_mean.fit(float_columns)

float_columns = imp_mean.transform(float_columns)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(float_columns)
print("after imputation:")
print(df_new.isna().sum())
```

the above returns:

```
0    5
1    6
2    5
3    6
4    4
dtype: int64
after imputation:
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `The scikit-learn version is 0.24.2.`  
`The pandas-learn version is 1.1.5.`  
`The numpy-learn version is 1.19.5.`  
Unfortunatly I can't share my data.

Comment: Can you try to store `pd.DataFrame(float_columns, columns = relevant_cols)` in a new dataframe and not use `df[relevant_cols] = pd.DataFrame(float_columns, columns = relevant_cols)`. Does this help? If not, somethings is really wrong with your data. Inspect step by step the outputs. Cannot help more without the data